# Android fragment exit animation not firing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have a fragment that slides in when it is added and slides off the screen to the right when it is removed. However, only the sliding in animation is working, and when I set the visibility of the fragment to gone, it vanishes without sliding. This is also my first post here so please let me know if I'm not doing something right, thanks!

### Activity code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in, R.animator.slide_out_right);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        MyFragment myFrag = new MyFragment();
        myFrag.setArguments(bundle);
        ft.add(R.id.challenger_preview_fragment_container, myFrag, "MyFragment");
        ft.commit();
}
```

### Fragment code

```
public void removeFragment() {
    getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

### Animation XML

#### slide_in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:valueFrom="1000"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
</set>
```

#### slide_out_right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:valueFrom="-1280"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="X"
        android:duration="2000" />
</set>
```

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code, in below create an animation object to slide out right and set the duration. Later create a listener to know when the animation is ending so that you can hide your view.

The problem in your above code is that you are hiding the view before the animation is ending.

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.animator.slide_out_right);
    animation.setDuration(800);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            try { 
                    getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        } 
    }); 

    //Start the animation.   
    getView().startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting visibility    `getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);`

So the fragment cannot come back again its GONE

Try `getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

And when it comes back make it visible again as `getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`